# Extract 1 and possibly 2 dates from a string in Pandas to new columns of their own

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY from a pandas dataframe column containing varying text regarding property leases. There are up to 3 data items in the text in each row:-

- Lease Duration
- Lease Start Date
- Lease End date

**Sample Incoming Strings**

75 years from 25/12/1975

125 years from 14/3/2019 until 13/3/2144

from 18/02/2011 to 24/03/2156

**Desired Output**

For each row:-

Extract the 1st date in the string to a new column Lease_Startdate

Extract the 2nd date in the string (if present) to a new column Lease_Enddate

**Help Required**

I am ok creating a regex to select the date format DD/MM/YYYY but I dont know how to allocate the 1st to column Lease_Startdate and the 2nd to column Lease_Enddate. i.e. deal with the occurence number

Most of the examples Ive seen here only reference a single date string.

Id be grateful for any advice...Thanks Mark

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.str.extract` with `regex`:

```
(r'(?P<Lease_Startdate>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})'            # match the 1st date
 r'(?:.*(?P<Lease_Enddate>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}))?')      # optionally match the 2nd date
```

Demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['75 years from 25/12/1975', '125 years from 14/3/2019 until 13/3/2144', 'from 18/02/2011 to 24/03/2156']})
df.text.str.extract(
  r'(?P<Lease_Startdate>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})'
  r'(?:.*(?P<Lease_Enddate>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}))?',
  expand=True)

#  Lease_Startdate Lease_Enddate
#0      25/12/1975           NaN
#1       14/3/2019      3/3/2144
#2      18/02/2011     4/03/2156
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Psidom...much appreciated. Unfortunately with less < 15 reputation score Im not allowed to vote.

Comment: @pekoz1 You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Hi @psidom Just trying to use your answer today .... for the strings that have 2 dates present in them the 2nd date "Lease_enddate" is having the 1st digit missed. So in the demo above 3/3/2144 should be 13/3/2144  and 4/03/2156 should be 24/03/2156.   Would you have any thoughts as to why the 2 digits are not being captured? Thanks Mark 
pekoz1
 37 mins ago    Delete

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.str.extractall` to capture all 3 groups at one go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Text":["75 years from 25/12/1975",
                           "125 years from 14/3/2019 until 13/3/2144",
                           "from 18/02/2011 to 24/03/2156"]})

print (df["Text"].str.extractall("(?P<Dur>\d+)?.+?(?=\d)(?P<Start>\d+/\d+/\d+).+?(?=\d)(?P<End>\d+/\d+/\d+)?")
                 .reset_index(drop=True))

   Dur       Start         End
0   75    25/12/19         NaN
1  125   14/3/2019   13/3/2144
2  NaN  18/02/2011  24/03/2156
```

Note that you need to adjust the regex pattern if you have more variations of data input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henry...much appreciated. Unfortunately with less < 15 reputation score Im not allowed to vote.

Comment: Just trying to use your answer today .... for the 1st sample string "75 years from 25/12/1975"  the last 2 digits of the year are not being returned. So its returning 25/12/19 instead of 25/12/1975 as the "Start" date.  However if I add a second date onto the string the start date then works correctly.  So "75 years from 25/12/1975 until 25/12/1985" is fine.      The underlying date selection regex seems fine.   Would you have any thoughts as to why?   Thanks Mark

Answer (score 1):

While the question doesn't state it, I'll post the below in case it's helpful if the text has dates in the format like `starting January 4th, 2017` (as contracts can contain those formats).

```
import datefinder # https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['75 years from 25/12/1975',
                           '125 years from 14/3/2019 until 13/3/2144',
                           'from 18/02/2011 to 24/03/2156',
                          'starting January 4th, 2017 and ending 13/3/2144']})

# currently looks like...
#                                               Text
# 0                         75 years from 25/12/1975
# 1         125 years from 14/3/2019 until 13/3/2144
# 2                    from 18/02/2011 to 24/03/2156
# 3  starting January 4th, 2017 and ending 13/3/2144



# compile a regex pattern to find a date
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})')

def findDates(s):
    # try to get datefinder to pull out the date
    d = pd.Series(datefinder.find_dates(s))
    if d.empty:
        # fallback is to use the regex
        d = pd.Series(pattern.findall(s))
        d = pd.to_datetime(d)
    return d

df[['Lease_Startdate', 'Lease_Enddate']] = df.apply(lambda x: findDates(x['Text']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Text                                             Lease_Startdate    Lease_Enddate
0   75 years from 25/12/1975                              1975-12-25              NaT
1   125 years from 14/3/2019 until 13/3/2144              2019-03-14       2144-03-13
2   from 18/02/2011 to 24/03/2156                         2011-02-18       2156-03-24
3   starting January 4th, 2017 and ending 13/3/2144       2017-01-04       2144-03-13
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply MDR. Much appreciated. I think its good to have more than one solution....